# Application Exception after adding facebook sdk?

Tags: android, facebook

My app is working good and activity is not crashed but when facebook sdk add in my app then my splash activity is crashed and gives exception in logcat is

E/AndroidRuntime(14873): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.book/com.example.book.SplashScreen}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Can any one tell me how to fix this?

Comment: did you declare "com.example.book.SplashScreen" in manifest.xml file?

Comment: Please provide some code. According to your error, it's simple: There's no such class.

Comment: This exception is caused by the library not being included in the apk, rather than anything in the manifest.  You'll need to make sure your build scripts are including all the right libraries.